# How to create custom burndown chart of all stories of a specific iteration?

Tags: rally

I need to create a custom burndown chart for the stories in a specific iteration. It needs to be custom because I need two different bars: one for accepted stories that were created in this current iteration, and one for the continued stories that were split and brought up from the previous sprint (with a different bar color obviously). I have been reading all the chart guides and examples, but I can't figure out how to query for stories of an iteration. The example on the rally guides shows a chart but with stories from a portfolio item. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about how to query this using Lookback API, correct?

You should just need to add another clause to your find for iteration:

```
find: {
    _TypeHierarchy: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
    Children: null,
    Iteration: 12345 // <-- your iteration oid
},
```

The Lookback API docs should be helpful as well:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual